# Unable To Target Frontpage Margin

Tags: css

Hello i have been at it for a couple of hours now. My CSS knowledge is starting to get there. I dont seem to be able to make my frontpage content left margin be overridden. All help appreciated thanks.

[my frontpage](http://onlinebanter.com/)

I have added-

> ## content {   padding:0 0px!important; }

to the page but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: i want to make the main coloum boxes on my frontpage line up on the left with the top block Anand. tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#content { padding: 0 !important; }
```

or increase priority

```
div#main-content div#content { padding: 0 !important; }
```

I just added div#main-content just for giving more priority, if not need better to remove it

Comment: Sorry Anand i havent voted anything. Must have been an error.

Comment: brilliant Anand that worked. I just had to move it to anither CSS file. Thanks to you and to Gung Foo

Answer (score 1):

your padding is introduced here:

```
.block, #user-menu, #skip-nav, #branding, #search-box, #mission, #primary-menu, #secondary-menu, #attribution, #breadcrumb, #main-content-header, #content, #messages-and-help, #footer-message {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: sorry gung Foo i think my # was taken out on my post. i have it as you say. Let me try your code just to be sure.....nah still not happening. Im a wondering if i should maybe change the left margin of the leaderboard box instead? Problem then being it puts it out when viewed on the latest page. ooops never meant to comment http://onlinebanter.com/latest/posts